Quasi-fuchsian representations rigidity when restricting the multiplicative constant of the associated QI embedding of H^2 in H^3?
Consider a quasi-fuchsian representation $\rho:\Gamma\to\mathrm{PO}(3,1)$ where $\Gamma$ is a cocompact lattice of $\mathrm{PO}(2,1)$.
This is a convex-cocompact representation, so it is a quasi-isometric embedding of $\Gamma$ into $\mathrm{PO}(3,1)$ at the level of groups. By the Svarc-Milnor lemma, $\Gamma$ itself is quasi-isometric to the orbit of any point $o\in\mathbb{H}^2$ (with the metric induced by $\mathbb{H}^2$), and you can interpret the previous quasi-isometric embedding as a quasi-isometric embedding of $\Gamma\cdot o$ into $\mathbb{H}^3$ using orbit maps. That is, for any points $o\in\mathbb{H}^2$ and $o'\in\mathbb{H}^3$, there are constants $K,C>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
   \frac1K d_{\mathbb{H}^2}(o,\gamma o) - C \leq d_{\mathbb{H}^3}(o',\rho(\gamma) o') \leq Kd_{\mathbb{H}^2}(o,\gamma o) + C
\end{equation}
for all $\gamma\in\Gamma$.
My question is the following. Suppose you can choose points $o\in\mathbb{H}^2$ and $o'\in\mathbb{H}^3$ such that the above quasi-isometric embedding satisfies
\begin{equation}
  \lambda d_{\mathbb{H}^2}(o,\gamma o) - C \leq d_{\mathbb{H}^3}(o',\rho(\gamma) o') \leq \lambda d_{\mathbb{H}^2}(o,\gamma o) + C
\end{equation}
for some $\lambda,C>0$, and for all $\gamma\in\Gamma$.
What are the implications for $\rho$? In particular, can you deduce that $\lambda=1$ and $\rho$ is fuchsian?
I'm pretty sure this is false (meaning you can get non fuchsian representations satisfying the above inequations for all $\lambda\in (0;1)$) if you replace $\mathbb{H}^3$ in the target by $\mathbb{H}^\infty$, by using some irreducible representations of $\mathrm{PO}(2,1)$ into $\mathrm{PO}(\infty,1)$ defined in Monod-Py “An exotic deformation of hyperbolic space” (see Theorem C), but I guess this result would not be as interesting in $\mathbb{H}^\infty$ if you could do the same thing in finite dimensional hyperbolic spaces. This is the reason I expect the conclusion that $\rho$ should be fuchsian, but this is no evidence.

I do not really understand your question. If $G\times X\to X$ is any isometric action of a f.g. group on a metric space and for one orbit $Gx$ you get a qi embedding then you get a qi embedding for all orbits $Gy$ and, hence, by transitivity of qi relation, you get inequalities  of the type $L^{-1} d(gy, y) -A \le d(gx, x)\le L d(gy, y) +A$. Are you asking for examples of actions which do not result in qi embeddings?

@MoisheKohan Yes, I know these are all QI embeddings. My question is if for one of these orbits, I have a particular stronger version of a QI embedding, what can you say. The strengthening is that instead of $L^{-1}$ on the left inequality, I also have $L$.

Oh, I see, I did not notice that constants are the same.

I just added an answer. If anyone knows a more elementary or classical approach, which only uses classical facts and theorems in hyperbolic geometry, I would be happy to accept it instead of mine.

A friend just mentioned to me a paper by Inkang Kim which solves this question. In “Marked length rigidity of rank one symmetric spaces
and their product”, he proves the following theorem (see Theorem A):
Theorem: Let $X$ and $Y$ be two rank one symmetric spaces, and $\rho_X:G\to\mathrm{Isom}(X)$ and $\rho_Y:G\to\mathrm{Isom}(Y)$ be two Zariski dense representations of a group $G$. If $\rho_X$ and $\rho_Y$ have proportional marked length spectrum, then $X=Y$ and $\rho_X$ and $\rho_Y$ are conjugated.
(observe that in the original theorem, it is not necessary that the entire marked length spectra of the representations are proportional, but only a large enough subset)
Here, the marked length spectrum of $\rho_X:G\to\mathrm{Isom}(X)$ is defined as the function $G\to\mathbb{R}$ mapping $g\in G$ to the translation length of $\rho_X(g)$:
\begin{equation}
   l(\rho_X(g)) = \inf_{x\in X} d(x,\rho_X(g)x)
\end{equation}
The marked length spectrum of $\rho_Y$ is defined similarly.
Here, we choose $X=\mathbb{H}^2$ and $Y=\mathbb{H}^3$.
We first observe that for any isometry $g\in\mathrm{Isom}(X)$,
\begin{equation}
  l(g) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n d(o,g^n o)
\end{equation}
for any point $o\in X$. That is because, for any $x\in X$,
\begin{align}
  nl(g) &= l(g^n) \\
  &\leq d(o,g^no)\\
  &\leq d(x,g^nx) + 2d(x,o) \\
  &\leq nd(x,gx) + 2d(x,o)
\end{align}
so that
\begin{equation}
  l(g)\leq \liminf_n\frac1nd(o,g^no)\leq\limsup_n\frac1nd(o,g^no)\leq d(x,gx)
\end{equation}
Since this holds for any $x\in X$, it follows that the limit exists and is equal to $l(g)$.
Now suppose we have $\rho:\Gamma\to\mathrm{PO}(3,1)$ where $\Gamma <\mathrm{PO}(2,1)$ is cocompact, such that for some $o\in\mathbb{H}^2$ and $o'\in\mathbb{H}^3$, we have
\begin{equation}\label{QIE}
  \lambda d(o,\gamma o) - C \leq d(o',\gamma o') \leq \lambda d(o,\gamma o) + C
\end{equation}
for some constants $\lambda,C>0$. (equation (*))
By contradiction, we suppose that $\rho$ is not fuchsian. Therefore, $\rho$ is irreducible in $\mathrm{PO}(3,1)$. We claim that equation (*) implies that the marked spectrum of $\rho$ is precisely $\lambda$ times the marked spectrum of the inclusion of $\Gamma$ into $\mathrm{PO}(2,1)$.
To see this, pick any $\gamma\in\Gamma$, and apply (*) with $\gamma^n$. Dividing by $n$ and taking the limit yields the result.
The theorem implies that $\mathbb{H}^2 = \mathbb{H}^3$, which is a contradiction. So $\rho$ is fuchsian.
Observe that the same argument applies to any “quasi-fuchsian like” representation of $\mathbb{H}^n$ into $\mathbb{H}^m$ for $m>n$. The representation into $\mathbb{H}^n$ may only be irreducible in the sense that it is non-elementary and does not preserve any non-trivial totally geodesic subspace.
